# Creating a number of kivy custom widgets with different variables

Tags: python, variables, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I have a function, that adds a custom widget for every item in a list.
The label (child of the custom widget) should display the item it was added for as a text(the item in watchlist_names). At its current state, every custom widget being added displays the same text. Which is obvious, all are referenced to the same variables. I have not yet found a way to reference the custom widget labels text to the list items.

Meaning the first widget added has label text: 'Secunet'
second widget added has label text: 'Wirecard'
and so forth...

### py file

```
# the variables and lists
watchlist_stock_ticker = StringProperty()
watchlist_stock_name = StringProperty()
watchlist_numbers = [0, 1]
watchlist_tickers = ['YSN.DE', 'WDI.DE']

# list with the variables to be displayed
watchlist_names = ['Secunet', 'Wirecard']

# the function to add the custom widgets
def load_stock_watchlist(self, layout):
    layout.clear_widgets()
    for n in self.watchlist_numbers:
        self.watchlist_stock_ticker = self.watchlist_tickers[n]
        self.watchlist_stock_name = self.watchlist_names[n]
        layout.add_widget(StockWatchlist())
```

and part of the custom widget (FloatLayout) including the label:

### kv file

```
<StockWatchlist>
    size_hint: None, None
    height: app.root.height * .13
    width: app.root.width -10

    Button:
        pos: root.pos
        on_release:
            app.go_screen(4)
            app.load_popup2()
            app.update_current(watchlistticker.text, watchlistcompany.text)
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        height: app.root.height * .13
        width: app.root.width -10

    # this is the label that should have its text matching
    # with the list item it was added for
        Label:
            text: app.watchlist_stock_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following enhancements are required to the Python script and kv file.

### py file

- Declare a class attribute, `watchlist_stock_name` and `watchlist_stock_ticker` in `class StockWatchList()`
- Pass stock name and ticker as parameters when initiating `StockWatchList` object.

#### Snippets - py file

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...

class StockWatchList(FloatLayout):
    watchlist_stock_ticker = StringProperty('')    # initialize to empty string
    watchlist_stock_name = StringProperty('')    # initialize to empty string


class class-name(...):
    # the variables and lists
    self.watchlist_numbers = [0, 1]
    self.watchlist_tickers = ['YSN.DE', 'WDI.DE']

    # list with the variables to be displayed
    self.watchlist_names = ['Secunet', 'Wirecard']

    # the function to add the custom widgets
    def load_stock_watchlist(self, layout):
        layout.clear_widgets()
        for n in self.watchlist_numbers:
            layout.add_widget(StockWatchlist(watchlist_stock_ticker=self.watchlist_tickers[n], watchlist_stock_name=self.watchlist_names[n]))
```

### kv file

- Replace `app.watchlist_stock_name` with `root.watchlist_stock_name`
- Replace `app.watchlist_stock_ticker` with `root.watchlist_stock_ticker`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<StockWatchlist>:
    size_hint: None, None
    height: app.root.height * .13
    width: app.root.width -10

    Button:
        pos: root.pos
        on_release:
            app.go_screen(4)
            app.load_popup2()
            app.update_current(watchlistticker.text, watchlistcompany.text)

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        height: app.root.height * .13
        width: app.root.width -10

        Label:
            text: root.watchlist_stock_name
```